# No Temporary Folder ( can't upload files )

Tags: php, html, ajax, iis

I run PHP though IIS 7.5 and made the php installation from http://windows.php.net/download/ 5.3 msi installer

To date everything has run very fine,

but for some reason when i submit a file with an html form,
In the php script that should save the file i get this the error 6 witch mean that there is no tmp_folder.

This is the output of print_r($_FILES);

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Book1.csv
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 6
        [size] => 0
    )
)
```

Now when i look in php.ini

I correctly have this

```
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = "C:\phpDevelopment\tmpFolder"
```

I don't know what to do to make this to work correctly.

I Googled this problem and i can't find any thing.

Any idea some one ?

Thanks for any help I could have.

Edit --------------------------------------------

Also yes the tmp folder at is there and should have the right to be able to write in.

I setted right to everyone just to make sure i have enough right.
[image: We see here that right are set to everyone]

Comment: try `echo sys_get_temp_dir();`

Comment: @Dagon I get this output :s "C:\Windows\TEMP"

Comment: did you restart after changing php.ini? `phpinfo()` will tell you which php.ini file you should be editing

Comment: @Dagon Yes I did restart. And also I just checked in phpinfo() the php.ini path and I can confirm that im editing the correct one.

Comment: Does the `C:\phpDevelopment\tmpFolder` exist? Does the application pool have Write access to this folder?

Comment: @BrockHensley-FKAdirt Yes it does exist, and just to be sure I setted "Everyone" with FullControl just to be sure.

Comment: Try commenting out `upload_tmp_dir` so that it uses the default %TMP%

Comment: @BrockHensley-FKAdirt I just just did that :P and it was not working as it was not having all permision. Now it is working on the %TMP% folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out `upload_tmp_dir` in your php.ini by putting a `;` in front of it so that it uses the default Windows Temp folder by default: `C:\Windows\Temp`

Also make sure your Application Pool Identity or group of Identity users has write permission to the temp folder.